# Measuring tests coverage in multi-module and dynamic feature module Android project using Jacoco

Tags: android, gradle, code-coverage, jacoco

I am currently developping a new Android application in which one I am trying to use the modularization principles.

My android project is composed of the folllowing modules:

- `app` of type `com.android.application`
- `core` of type `com.android.library`
- `home` of type `com.android.dynamic-feature`

I would like to produce an unified code coverage report for the CI (Azure Pipeline) in which one I can see the global code coverage of unit tests and instrumented tests for all the modules.

I read so many articles and tried several custom jacoco gradle plugins in order to produce a such report with no success.

I finally wrote the following `jacoco.gradle` file:

```
apply plugin: 'jacoco'

tasks.withType(Test) {
  jacoco.includeNoLocationClasses = true
  jacoco.excludes = ['jdk.internal.*']
}

project.afterEvaluate {
}
tasks.create(name: "createUnifiedCoverageReport", type: JacocoReport, dependsOn: [
':app:testInternalDebugUnitTest', ':app:createInternalDebugCoverageReport',
':home:testInternalDebugUnitTest', ':home:createInternalDebugCoverageReport',
':core:testDebugUnitTest', ':core:createDebugCoverageReport',
]) {

  reports
  {
    html.enabled = true
    xml.enabled = true
    csv.enabled = false
  }

  def fileFilter = [ 
    //some files to filter
  ]

  classDirectories.setFrom(files([
  //app
  fileTree(dir: "$project.rootDir/app/build/tmp/kotlin-classes/internalDebug", excludes: fileFilter),
  fileTree(dir: "$project.rootDir/app/build/intermediates/javac/internalDebug", excludes: fileFilter),

  //home
  fileTree(dir: "$project.rootDir/home/build/tmp/kotlin-classes/debug", excludes: fileFilter),
  fileTree(dir: "$project.rootDir/home/build/intermediates/javac/debug", excludes: fileFilter),

  //core
  fileTree(dir: "$project.rootDir/core/build/tmp/kotlin-classes/debug", excludes: fileFilter),
  fileTree(dir: "$project.rootDir/core/build/intermediates/javac/debug", excludes: fileFilter),
  ]))

  def coverageSourceDirs = [
  //app
  "$project.rootDir/app/src/main/java",
  "$project.rootDir/app/src/main/kotlin",

  //home
  "$project.rootDir/home/src/main/java",
  "$project.rootDir/home/src/main/kotlin",

  //core
  "$project.rootDir/core/src/main/java",
  "$project.rootDir/core/src/main/kotlin",
  ]

  additionalSourceDirs.setFrom(files(coverageSourceDirs))
  sourceDirectories.setFrom(files(coverageSourceDirs))

  def uiAppTestsData = fileTree(dir: "${project.rootDir}/app/build/outputs/code_coverage/internalDebugAndroidTest/connected/", includes: ["**/*.ec"])
  def uiHomeTestsData = fileTree(dir: "${project.rootDir}/home/build/outputs/code_coverage/internalDebugAndroidTest/connected/", includes: ["**/*.ec"])
  def uiCoreTestsData = fileTree(dir: "${project.rootDir}/core/build/outputs/code_coverage/debugAndroidTest/connected/", includes: ["**/*.ec"])

  executionData(files([
  //app
  uiAppTestsData,
  "$project.rootDir/app/build/jacoco/testInternalDebugUnitTest.exec",

  //home
  uiHomeTestsData,
  "$project.rootDir/home/build/jacoco/testInternalDebugUnitTest.exec",

  //core
  uiCoreTestsData,
  "$project.rootDir/core/build/jacoco/testDebugUnitTest.exec",
  ]))
}
```

This `jacoco.gradle` is then applied in each module with the following instruction:

```
apply from: '../jacoco.gradle'
```

So, in order to create the unified code coverage report, I use the gradle task `createUnifiedCoverageReport`.

The task create an unified code coverage report that contains the classe of the `app` and the `core` modules. But the classes from the `home` module is missing from this report.

So I have several questions:

- how to modify my Jacoco configuration in order to produce an unified code coverage report that includes unit tests and instrumented tests for the 3 modules?
- Is it possible to do that with the "pure" jacoco gradle plugin or should I use a more Android oriented one?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The configuration was OK but the path of the classes for the module was incorrect. The flavor information was missing :

```
fileTree(dir: "$project.rootDir/home/build/tmp/kotlin-classes/internalDebug", excludes: fileFilter),
fileTree(dir: "$project.rootDir/home/build/intermediates/javac/internalDebug", excludes: fileFilter),
```